# Ionic Framework - Unit testing controller using $ionicView.enter

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ionic-framework

I'm trying to unit test a controller that uses $ionicView.enter like this

```
myControllers.controller('MyCtrl', [
'$scope',
function($scope) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    $scope.myValue = 1;
  });

}]);
```

In my unit test I can spy on the event and check it's been called, but it doesn't then get into the function and set $scope.myValue. This is my test:

```
it('should do stuff', function () {
    spyOn(scope, '$on').and.callThrough();
    scope.$on('$ionicView.enter');

    // this passes
    expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('$ionicView.enter')
    // this fails - scope.myValue is undefined
    expect(scope.myValue).toEqual(1);
});
```

I thought callThrough would call the code inside the function I'm spying on, but doesn't seem to here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to trigger the ionicView enter event after my controller set up in the test rather than try to spy on it.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

  $controller('MyCtrl', {
    $scope: scope
  });

  scope.$emit('$ionicView.enter');

  scope.$digest();
}));
```